# How to re-write <html> tag on platforms that don't allow it?

Tags: amp-html

I'm on a platform that meets the requirements of Google AMP except for one in particular; I can't rename the `<html>` tag. It seems like an arbitrary requirement compared to everything else, so I'm hoping there's *some* way of indicating to Google it is an AMP page without modifying it.

Has anyone successfully worked around re-writing the opening  tag?

Comment: Here is an [AMP HTML Specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec) to help you start with. To know more about components and tags, you can refer to [this document](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components). [Additional details in order for google to detect the AMP version of your work](https://searchengineland.com/get-started-accelerated-mobile-pages-amp-240688). *In order for Google (and other technologies supporting the AMP Project) to detect the AMP version of your article, you will need to modify the original version of the article page.*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the opening `html` tag *must* contain either the `⚡` or `amp` attribute in order to become a valid AMP page.

Unless the [AMP HTML Specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec) changes, I doubt what you're trying to achieve is possible, unless the page is pre-processed where you could manipulate the opening `<html>` tag with `preg_replace` (or similar), though this is by no means an elegant solution.

**Resources**

- [Required Mark-Up](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create/basic_markup#required-mark-up)
- [AMP HTML Specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec)
- [PHP :: preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)